# Jquery select 2 не выбирается первый элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Всем привет, ситуация такая.
Использую jQuery Select2. Использую для выбора нужного города.
Первый список городов получаю без проблем и выбираю нужный город также без проблем.
Если ищу город с помощью поиска, (при этом поле в котором должно быть значение не пустое), тогда первый город не могу выбрать (он еще серым подсвечен). После выбора первого города из списка, остается в поле город который был до этого.
Файлы архив с файлами во вложениях.
https://yadi.sk/d/U93oSl1Wwgyl7g
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код с проблемный местом выложите здесь, пжлст

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/U93oSl1Wwgyl7g